# R ggplot2 x-axis not properly show

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, axis-labels

My question is in the following.
here is my raw data:

```
type,com,year,month,value
A,CH,2016,1,0
A,CH,2016,2,0
A,CH,2016,3,0
A,CH,2016,4,0
A,CH,2016,5,0
A,CH,2016,6,0
A,CH,2016,7,0
A,CH,2016,8,0
A,CH,2016,9,453128
A,CH,2016,10,868256
A,CH,2016,11,1015080
A,CH,2016,12,650912
B,CH,2016,1,0
B,CH,2016,2,0
B,CH,2016,3,0
B,CH,2016,4,0
B,CH,2016,5,0
B,CH,2016,6,61273
B,CH,2016,7,27711
B,CH,2016,8,161780
B,CH,2016,9,48889
B,CH,2016,10,72805
B,CH,2016,11,131466
B,CH,2016,12,73756
C,CH,2016,1,0
C,CH,2016,2,0
C,CH,2016,3,0
C,CH,2016,4,0
C,CH,2016,5,0
C,CH,2016,6,0
C,CH,2016,7,0
C,CH,2016,8,2200
C,CH,2016,9,111384
C,CH,2016,10,28758
C,CH,2016,11,21161
C,CH,2016,12,0
```

I use it to plot a line graph with *gglot2*.

The code is:

```
test <- read.csv("test.csv", header = T)
test_list <- split(test, test$type)
Rplot <- ggplot(test_list$A, aes(x=month, y=value, col=com))+geom_line()
Rplot
```

[image: Rplot]

My question:
how to let my x-axis to display like *month*(1,2,3....,12)?
and how can I combine *year* and *month* showing on x-axis at the same time.(Jan2016, Feb2016,.....) or (2016/1, 2016/2,.....)

very appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create `date_label` column as `Date` class in the dataframe using `ymd()` from `lubridate` package.

```
library( 'lubridate' )
test_list <- lapply( test_list, function( x ) { 
  x$date_label <- ymd( paste( x$year, month.abb[ x$month ], 01, sep = "-"))
  x 
  })
```

**Manipulate x axis using `scale_x_date()`**

```
# 1. date_labels = "%Y/%m"   - 2016/01
# 2. date_labels = "%m"      - 01
# 3. date_labels = "%b %Y"   - Jan 2016        

library( 'ggplot2' )
ggplot( data = test_list$A, aes( x = date_label, y = value, color = com, group = com ) ) +
  geom_line( size = 3 ) + 
  scale_x_date(name = "month",
               date_labels = "%m", 
               date_breaks = "1 month" )
```

[image]

```
ggplot( data = test_list$A, aes( x = date_label, y = value, group = com, color = com ) ) +
  geom_line(  size = 3 ) + 
  theme( axis.text.x = element_text( angle = 45, hjust = 1 )) +
  scale_x_date(name = "month_year",
               date_labels = "%b %Y", 
               date_breaks = "1 month" )
```

[image]

Comment: thanks. how can I adjust my plot's width and height? Because if my data has many rows, the x-axis will become too crowd.

Comment: are you talking about fixing aspect ratio

Comment: aspect ratio: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056836/how-to-fix-the-aspect-ratio-in-ggplot

Comment: figure width and height: depends on the graphics device used to create the graph. For list of graphic devices, see `capabilities()`. To create a jpeg image, you would use `jpeg()` device. For pdf, it will be `pdf()`

Comment: oh. sorry for my ambiguous description. I mean my plot's x-axis  have too many value(year+month), how to let them display explicitly and properly.

Comment: Also, I see the graph u post above is awesome. The x-axis display Jan 2016, Feb2016,...,Dec2016 and these labels tilt about 45 degrees. However, my plot's x-axis shows Chinese(like 一月 2016, 二月 2016....) and does not tilt(it shows horizontal), how to change this. Very Appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, you can convert month to be a factor. The following code would eliminate decimals in the month.

```
test$month <- as.factor(test$month)
test_list <- split(test, test$type)
Rplot <- ggplot(test_list$A, aes(x=month, y=value, col=com, group = 1))+geom_line()
Rplot
```

[image]

To get numeric months you have to have a new column. I will create a new one using `dplyr` package and change that.

```
library(dplyr)
# make a new column by joining month after converting it to character and year.
test <- test %>% mutate(exactDate = paste(month.abb[as.numeric(as.character(month))], year, sep=""))

# convert to factor
test$exactDate <- factor(test$exactDate, levels = c("Jan2016","Feb2016","Mar2016","Apr2016","May2016","Jun2016",
                                                    "Jul2016","Aug2016","Sep2016", "Oct2016", "Nov2016", "Dec2016"),
                         labels =  c("Jan2016","Feb2016","Mar2016","Apr2016","May2016","Jun2016",
                                    "Jul2016","Aug2016","Sep2016", "Oct2016", "Nov2016", "Dec2016"))

# Plot similarly
test_list <- split(test, test$type)
Rplot <- ggplot(test_list$A, aes(x=exactDate, y=value, col=com, group = 1))+geom_line()

# Rotate axis labels by 90 degrees
Rplot+ theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))
```

[image]

Comment: I got this Error: Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'exactDate' not found

Comment: `test <- test %>% mutate(exactDate = paste(month.abb[as.numeric(as.character(month))], year, sep=""))` should add a column named exactDate and this error should not occur.